# How to create VVVVVV (game) launcher?

Tags: launcher, games

I recently bought VVVVVV (game) from the Ubuntu Software Centre. Sadly, there is no desktop launcher for the game! Meaning, I can't find it using the dash. When I enter /usr/share/applications though, the game is there. When I click it, this pops up:

[image]

Clicking "Run" starts the game perfectly, but this isn't a user friendly way of starting it. Is there a way to create a desktop launcher for VVVVVV?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instructions on the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Essentially, you make a file with contents like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/usr/share/applications/VVVVVV
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Then save it as a `*.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`

You can also use the [Desktop File Validator](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/desktop-file-validate.1.html) to make sure you did it right.